# How to create Javascript 2-d array like in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying  to replicate the 2d array generation in java-script form the following PHP code I have written, I am feeling I am getting some misconception because I am not getting the expected result from my javascript.
Help me out where I am doing it wrong and what is my misconception.

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php

    $checkArray = array();
    for($m=0; $m<3; $m++){
        for($n=0; $n<4; $n++ )
        {
            $checkArray[$m][$n] = "Inside_ ".$m." is ".$n;
        }
    }   

    var_dump($checkArray);
?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script>
        function ArrayFunction(){
            var checkArray = [];
            for(var m=0; m<3; m++){
               checkArray[m] = []; 
               for(var n=0; n<4; n++){
                checkArray[m][n] = "Inside " +m+ " is " + n ;
              }
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < checkArray.length; i++)
              console.log(checkArray[i]);
        }
</script>    
</head>
<body>
   The content of the document......
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="ArrayFunction();" />

</body>
</html>
```

After **@sifriday** suggestion, I moved the array initialization outside inner loop,

**Updated Question:** 
But why do we have to initialize it everytime we need to expand the dimension unlike php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your initialisation of the inner array outside the for loop, that should fix it. Otherwise you're resetting it every time. Like this:

```
    function ArrayFunction(){
        var checkArray = [];
        for(var m=0; m<3; m++){

          // Move this to here!
          checkArray[m] = []; 

          for(var n=0; n<4; n++){

            checkArray[m][n] = "Inside " +m+ " is " + n ;
          }
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < checkArray.length; i++)
          console.log(checkArray[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Adding onto this: it's also probably better to use Array.prototype.push to add items to `checkArray[m]` like so: `checkArray[m].push( "Inside " +m+ " is " + n);`

Comment: @sifriday Oh thanks !! that was the blunder I am doing :) .. Can you suggest me some good online source to study the JavaScript and best approach to follow.

Comment: @sifriday I updated the question as per your suggestion, with a bit new query.

Comment: Thanks nmarsh, +1. Stackup, the answer to your new query is simply that PHP's array handling is pretty good, and you get a lot of flexibility with both multidimensional arrays and associative arrays. In JavaScript the language requires you you go in two stages. If you tried to do it one and call `checkArray[m][n]` then initially the value of checkArray[m] is `undefined` so this code will fail. So first you need to define it `checkArray[m] = []` and only then can you do `checkArray[m][n]`